# How do I create a new record on an association in a Devise managed model using Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Simple Form and Devise.

On my `registrations/edit.html.erb`, I have the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: "edit-user-form m-t" }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'col-lg-4 form-control' %>

      <%= f.input_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.input_field :current_password, hint: "we need your current password to confirm your changes", placeholder: "current password", required: true %>

    <h3 class="text-center">Change Password</h3>
      <%= f.input_field :password, autocomplete: "off", hint: "leave it blank if you don't want to change it", placeholder: "new password", required: false %>
      <%= f.input_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "confirm new password", required: false %>

      <h3 class="text-center">School</h3>

          <%= f.association :school, collection:  School.where(school_type: [:college, :university]), prompt: "Choose a school", class: 'col-lg-4 form-control', label: false %>

      <div class="alert alert-warning col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 text-center">
          <p>NB: If you can't find your school in the list above, please add it in the field below.</p>
      <%#= f.input_field some_random_field_that_collects_this_school_name %> 
      </div>

        <%= f.button :submit, "Update", class: "btn btn-lg edit-account-update-button" %>

<% end %>
```

What I want to do is if the school for the User is not currently in our DB, I want them to submit the name of their school.

This is the db schema for `School.rb`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: schools
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                 :string
#  school_type          :integer
#  created_at           :datetime         not null
#  updated_at           :datetime         not null
```

Where `school_type` is an enum value:

```
enum school_type: { high_school: 0, college: 1, university: 2 }
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the `school` on the fly at registration, allow your `user` (or whatever you're plugging into devise) to accept nested attributes for a `school`.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school, reject_if: :school_exists

  def school_exists(attributes)
    !School.where(name: attributes['name'], school_type: attributes['school_type']).empty?
  end
end

# app/controllers/user.rb
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_school
end    

# app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
...
<p>NB: If you can't find your school in the list above, please add it in the field below.</p>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :school do |s|  %> 
   <%= s.input :name %> 
   <%= s.input :school_type, :collection => %w[high_school college university] %> 
<% end %>
...
```

If you're using strong parameters, don't forget to update the `user_params` method in the `userController` to explicitly allow these parameters.

Helpful info:

- [simple-form Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)
- [Nested Forms in RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms)

Comment: You might want to use `reject_if: :existing_school` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so that no duplicate schools will be created accidentally. (you need to write your own `existing_school` method of course)

Comment: @EJ2015 Good call! Edited to add.

Comment: Since I am using Devise, can I just do this in my `registrations_controller#edit` rather than my `users_controller#edit`? I don't actually have a `users_controller`, but I do have a `RegistrationsController`. So that's why I am asking.

Comment: @marcamillion research indicates that may be able to omit it altogether - it's not mentioned in the [RoR API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). However, it is explicitly called out in the [simple_form docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models), so ymmv.